# How to delete a row of matrix in julia

Tags: matlab, julia

In matlab, deleting the 2nd row of matrix A  is

> A(2,:) = [];

How to delete a row of matrix in julia? I tried to use `A(2,:) = []`. but I failed. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:matlab]? This has nothing to do with MatLab

Comment: @KronoS Actually I think this is still MATLAB related, like many other comparison questions (_e.g_ "how to perform this MATLAB operation in Python?")...

Comment: A quick update: for vectors, Julia v0.3 has the `deleteat!` function, which is very fast. For matrices/arrays, you still need to use the solution of @EitanT

Answer (score 21):

You can't delete a row from a matrix – the fact that Matlab has easy syntax for this is a bit of a trap because the actual way you have to delete a row is to create a copy without the row so we decided to make that explicit and thereby have more transparent performance characteristics. You can change the size of 1-dimensional arrays, e.g. doing `push!(v,x)` and `pop!(v)`.

Comment: even worse: in MATLAB a copy is made for both row/column slicing (even though MATLAB uses a column-major order, so it would have been easy to a create view into the original matrix for the column indexing case). I think the exceptions are `A(:)`, `reshape(A,..)`, and some cases of `permute(A,..)`

Comment: Just my 2 cents: I don't think the performance hit is too surprising to anyone who is seriously concerned with performance *and* this feature is **really** nice. For example, a friend of mine who generally doesn't have anything nice to say about R really likes that you can do `noRow10Mat = mat[-10,]`.

Comment: Julia also makes a copy whenever you slice:  the temporary has to go somewhere...    You could sort of make an iterator across indices and not alter the storage of the array I suppose. There would be a cost to storing and maintaining an index structure alongside the array, which would quickly become a mess.  No, there is no easy way to avoid copying and allocating something.  So, we have hashtables--faster if you are going to change their size often; slower if you want to do lots of accesses--as for matrix mathematical operations.  You picks your data structure...

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the shortest answer
A[1:size(A,1) .!= 2,: ]

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/goVB9Pp74H4

Comment: You can just use `end` there.  I often use `A[setdiff(1:end, 2), :]`, but indexing by `1:end .!= 2` might be even faster.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the first thing about Julia, but I think it uses square brackets (`[]`) for [indexing](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.1/manual/arrays/#indexing), so you should try the following:

```
A[2, :] = []
```

I don't have a Julia interpreter at hand to test that, but if that also fails, surely the following should work:

```
A = A[[1, 3:end], :]
```

which simply uses the reverse strategy of selecting the rows that you want to keep.

Comment: I think Eitan is right, see more in this documentation... http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/

Comment: Julia makes a distinction between a 1-d array and a 1xN array. You should write `A[[1,3:end],:]` (with a comma to concatenate): http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/getting-started/#noteworthy-differences-from-matlab . The first solution suggested is not valid

Comment: This answer is outdated as of 2020 - Thuener has the right answer

Answer (score 0):

the following works in julia 1.7.2

```
 a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
 a[Not(1), :]
```