# How to index all but select indices?

Tags: arrays, julia

I have an array `a=rand(100)`, I want to get every value except the values at the indices `notidx=[2;50]`. Is there a clean way to get `a` at the other values? I am looking for a good way to do both a copy and a view.

Currently I make the array `[1;3:49;51:100]` by `symdiff(1:100,notidx)`, but `a[symdiff(1:length(a),notidx)]` and `view(a,a[symdiff(1:length(a),notidx)])` are not very clean (or understandable to others) ways of doing this.

Comment: Very similar to (but not quite a duplicate of): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298586/how-to-delete-a-row-of-matrix-in-julia

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have anything super clean, but you can do

```
a[setdiff(1:end, notidx)]
```

which is slightly cleaner than what you had, or

```
ind = trues(length(a))
ind[notidx] = false
a[ind]
```

which is pretty verbose but very clear.

Answer (score 10):

### Update:

If you are using julia-v0.5+, you can also use the new generator expression, for example:

```
view(a, [i for i in indices(a)... if i ∉ notidx])
```

and

```
[a[i] for i in indices(a)... if i ∉ notidx]
```

### Old post:

To get a copy, you can firstly make a copy of `a`, then manipulate it with `deleteat!` to delete those values at specific indices. <strike>After you've done this, it's convenient to get a view of `a` via `indexin`:</strike>

```
a = rand(100)         
# => 100-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.62636  
 0.488919 
 0.499884 
 ....

b = copy(a)           
deleteat!(b, [2,50])  
# => 98-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.62636  
 0.499884 
 ....
```

Comment: I definitely don't want to be making a copy to make a view. And using `indexin` won't be very efficient since it has to search the array `n` times. Using `deleteat!` is a good idea though.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I misunderstood that you wanted to get a copy and a view at the same time. Indeed, `indexin` is a overkill here.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas just found julia0.5's new generator expression is quite concise and understandable, see my updates above.

Comment: That is really nice. Slightly verbose, but easy to understand.