# Better algorithm to construct a matrix using vcat() or hcat() in a loop in Julia?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, julia

To use `vcat(a,b)` and `hcat(a,b)`, one must match the number of columns or number of rows in the matrices `a` and `b`.

When constructing a matrix using `vact(a, b)` or `hcat(a, b)` in a loop, one needs an initial matrix `a` (like a starting statement). Although all the sub-matrices are created in the same manner, I might need to construct this initial matrix `a` outside of the loop.

For example, if the loop condition is `for i in 1:w`, then I would need to pre-create `a` using `i = 1`, then start the loop with `for i in 2:w`.

If there is a nested loop, then my method is very awkward. I have thought the following methods, but it seems they don't really work:

1. Use a dummy `a`, delete `a` after the loop. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298586/how-to-delete-a-row-of-matrix-in-julia), we cannot delete row in a matrix. If we use another variable to refer to the useful rows and columns, we might waste some memory allocation.
2. Use `reshape()` to make an empty dummy `a`. It works for 1 dimension, but not multiple dimensions.

   ```
   julia> a = reshape([], 2, 0)
   2×0 Array{Any,2}

   julia> b = hcat(a, [3, 3])
   2×1 Array{Any,2}:
    3
    3

   julia> a = reshape([], 2, 2)
   ERROR: DimensionMismatch("new dimensions (2,2) must be consistent with array size 0")
    in reshape(::Array{Any,1}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64}) at ./array.jl:113
    in reshape(::Array{Any,1}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N}) at ./reshapedarray.jl:39
   ```

So my question is how to work around with `vcat()` and `hcat()` in a loop?

**Edit**: 
Here is the problem I got stuck in:

There are many gray pixel images. Each one is represented as a 20 by 20 `Float64` array. One function `foo(n)` randomly picks `n` of those matrices, and combine them to a big square.

If `n` has integer square root, then `foo(n)` returns a `sqrt(n) * 20` by `sqrt(n) * 20` matrix.

If `n` does not have integer square root, then `foo(n)` returns a `ceil(sqrt(n)) * 20` by `ceil(sqrt(n)) * 20` matrix. On the last row of the big square image (a row of 20 by 20 matrices), `foo(n)` fills `ceil(sqrt(n)) ^ 2 - n` extra black images (each one is represented as `zeros(20,20)`).

My current algorithm for `foo(n)` is to use a nested loop. In the inner loop, `hcat()` builds a layer (consisting `ceil(sqrt(n))` images). In the outer loop, `vcat()` combines those layers.

Then dealing with `hcat()` and `vcat()` in a loop becomes complicated.

Comment: Assuming you can't preallocate, a common trick in this situation is to avoid `vcat` or `hcat` entirely by building a `Vector{Vector{T}}` dynamically by using `push!` or `append!`, and then convert the result to a matrix when you're done (the final conversion is unlikely to have a performance impact on your routine except in unusual cases). I suspect this will be significantly faster than looping over calls to `vcat` as long as you're careful to take advantage of column-major order...

Comment: @ColinTBowers If I am building a big Multi-dimensional matrix from many small Multi-dimensional matrices, it might be complicated to compress each small matrix then apply `push!` or `append!` to each element of that matrix. Are there better ways to deal with this situation?

Comment: The common julia syntax is to preallocate the array, then fill it in the loop. Is that not possible here?

Comment: Could you give a minimal example of the kind of thing you want to do?

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard I just added an example, I am not sure how to preallocate the big square matrix and then fill it.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Sorry for the vagueness. I just added an example,

Comment: Looking at your edit, it appears that the length of both dimensions of your final matrix are predetermined, which means you can, and indeed should, preallocate, as others in this thread have suggested. So disregard my suggestions involving `push!` and `append!` as they are for situations where the final length is unable to be pre-determined. The single answer currently provided looks sensible to me, i.e. loop over indices in the preallocated matrix that denote 20x20 squares.

Comment: @ColinTBowers Yeah, I see now. Preallocation is a much more natural way to create a matrix. I was constrained in `vcat()` and `hcat()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So would:

```
pickimage() = randn(20,20)
n = 16
m = ceil(Int, sqrt(n))
out = Matrix{Float64}(20m, 20m)
k = 0
for i in (1:m)-1
   for j in (1:m)-1
       out[20i + (1:20), 20j + (1:20)] .= ((k += 1) <= n) ? pickimage() : zeros(20,20)
   end
end
```

be a relevant solution?